# CSS transition from background color to background image

Tags: css

I am having a page transition from a `background-color` to a `background-image`.  I have tried a variety of options...but it seems when the page transitions to the background image, it needs some `background-color`, and sets `background-color:transparent`..and the image never shows.  Here is my CSS:

```
@keyframes backgroundintro {
    0% {
      background:#000000;   

    }

     25% {
        background:#0c2336;
     }

     100% {


     background:  linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ), url('../IMG/background.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
   /*isolation: isolate;
   mix-blend-mode: color-burn;*/

     }


 }


body {



   animation-duration: 43.90s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;

    animation-name:backgroundintro;





}
```

I'm blending a background-color and the background-image..so using a gradient.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7god9hoL/

Comment: Please create a working fiddle.

Comment: @Amit "working" in the sense of "that demonstrates your problems".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick really is to make a background image transparent. This can be achieved by using pseudo-element (e.g. `:before`) which covers your main element (hence the `absolute` positioninig and `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` set to `0`). Then the as an animation you just change the `opacity` of this pseudo-element. Here's a simple example:

(*after running the snippet hover the square*)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: url('http://www.bestmanspeechestoasts.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg');
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```